# Passing function as a prop in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass a function inside a component as a prop to another component.

I have the following:

```
// Parent Component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const IncrementingCount = () => (
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
   const increment = () => {
     return setCount(count +1)
   };
   <ul>
     <li>
       My count:{count} <IncreaseCount onclick={IncrementingCount} />
     </li>
   </ul>
)
    
//Child component
import React from 'react'
const IncreaseCount = (IncrementingCount) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={IncrementingCount}> Click Me </button> 
  );
};
```

I'm completely new to React.

Comment: Please have a look at the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: is this just an example to know how to pass a function as a prop or is it an actual code?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of syntax issues here.

I suggest you go over the react basics here to make sure you're solid on the fundamentals. https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

IncreaseCount is your child component, so you need to pass something to it's props by providing an attribute. These can be named anything - but I'd steer away from defaults like onclick, as these are used for html buttons. (unless your component is a button, or has button-like behaviour). Here I think a good name would be onIncrementCount or something similar.

The value inside `onIncrementCount={VALUE}` is the thing you're passing. So this should be the function which increments the count. I've renamed this again - a good pattern is props to use the on-prefix, and for handlers to use the handle-prefix.

```
  <IncreaseCount onIncrementCount={handleIncrementCount} />
```

```
const IncrementingCount = () => (
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  // This is the handler function you'll pass to your child IncreaseCount component
  const handleIncrementCount = () => {
    return setCount(count +1)
  };

  <ul>
    <li>
      My count:{count} <IncreaseCount onIncrementCount={handleIncrementCount} />
    </li>
  </ul>
)
```

Lastly in your child component - you access via the props argument to the function. Here it's the name you bound to here -  `<IncreaseCount onIncrementCount={handleIncrementCount} />` - onIncrementCount so you need `props.onIncrementCount`.

```
//Child component
import React from 'react'

const IncreaseCount = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.onIncrementCount}> Click Me </button> 
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I jumped in deeply without knowing how to swim. You are right I'm  reading about props and trying to understand it and came across this challenge.

Comment: No worries - easily done! Could you accept an answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `increment` as a prop to your child, then you can access the function using `props.onClick` in the child.

Every prop you passed to the component can be accessed from `props` object.

```
import React from  'react'

const IncrementingCount = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  const increment = () => {
    return setCount(count +1)
  };

  return <ul>
    <li>
      My count:{count} <IncreaseCount onClick={increment} />
    </li>
  </ul>
}


const IncreaseCount = (props) => {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}> Click Me </button> 
}
```

More, importantly, learn the basics of React first. Watch a few video tutorials about React. and then build a project on your own.

Comment: Thanks, As you mentioned I need to learn a bit more and not to try do challenges or building projects.

Comment: no worries - we've all been there! No doubt you've heard it a million times, but taking the time now will save you time down the line

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow64102251-j4eoi

I have fixed your code. Read React Documentation or Watch Youtube Tutorials. You have a long road ahead.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const IncrementingCount = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const increment = () => {
    return setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        My count:{count}
        <IncreaseCount IncrementingCount={increment} />
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

//Child component
// import React from 'react'
const IncreaseCount = (props) => {
  const { IncrementingCount } = props;
  return <button onClick={IncrementingCount}> Click Me </button>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the the clarification, I was using the 2 components separately.